# Правильно ли иметь столько типов для ответов?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, .net-core

Для упрощения написания ответов сервером, я написал 2 основных контейнера, которые так же могут быть в некоторых случаях контейнерами, и вот встал вопрос, а правильно ли иметь столько дополнительных типов?

До того как описал все типы приведенные ниже, использовал анонимные типы.
Можно ли эти контейнеры улучшить?

```cs
public enum ResponseType
{
    Error,
    Success,
    BadRequest,
    Forbidden,
    Fail
}

public class StudioShortInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Uri Logotype { get; set; }
    public int SerialsCount { get; set; }
}

public class SingleStudioInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Uri Logotype { get; set; }

    public Container<SerialShortInfo> Serials { get; set; }
}

public class Result<T>
{
    public Result(int code, ResponseType type, T response)
    {
        Code = code;
        Type = type.ToString();
        Response = response;
    }

    public Result()
    {
    }

    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public T Response { get; set; }
}

public class Container<T>
{
    public int ItemsCount { get; set; }
    public ICollection<T> Items { get; set; }
}

public class CountryShortInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ResultError<T>
{
    public uint Code { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public T InvalidValue { get; set; }
}

public class SerialShortInfo
{
    public SerialShortInfo()
    {
    }

    public SerialShortInfo(int id, string title, string originalTitle, string description, int year,
        CountryShortInfo country, DateTime dateOfIssue, Uri previewImageUri, bool isMovie, int? seriesCount,
        int? currentSeriesCount)
    {
        Id = id;
        Title = title;
        OriginalTitle = originalTitle;
        Description = description;
        Year = year;
        Country = country;
        DateOfIssue = dateOfIssue;
        PreviewImageUri = previewImageUri;
        IsMovie = isMovie;
        SeriesCount = seriesCount;
        CurrentSeriesCount = currentSeriesCount;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string OriginalTitle { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public CountryShortInfo Country { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfIssue { get; set; }
    public Uri PreviewImageUri { get; set; }
    public bool IsMovie { get; set; }
    public int? SeriesCount { get; set; }
    public int? CurrentSeriesCount { get; set; }
}

public class SingleGenreInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Container<SerialShortInfo> Serials { get; set; }
}

public class GenreShortInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int SerialsCount { get; set; }
}
```

Генерация отдаваемых результатов выглядят примерно так:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<Result<Container<StudioShortInfo>>>> GetStudios()
{
    IQueryable<StudioShortInfo> studios = _context.Studios.Select(studio =>
        new StudioShortInfo
        {
            Id = studio.Id,
            Name = studio.Name,
            Logotype = studio.Logotype,
            SerialsCount = studio.Serials.Count
        });

    return new Result<Container<StudioShortInfo>>
    {
        Code = 200,
        Type = ResponseType.Success.ToString(),
        Response = new Container<StudioShortInfo>
        {
            ItemsCount = studios.Count(),
            Items = await studios.ToListAsync()
        }
    };
}

[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Result<SingleStudioInfo>>> GetStudio(int id)
{
    if (!StudioExists(id))
    {
        return NotFound(new Result<ResultError<int>>
        {
            Code = 404,
            Type = ResponseType.Fail.ToString(),
            Response = new ResultError<int>
            {
                Message = $"Studio with id: {id} does not exits.",
                Code = 12u,
                InvalidValue = id
            }
        });
    }

    Studio studio = await _context.Studios
        .AsQueryable()
        .Where(g => g.Id == id)
        .Include(g => g.Serials)
        .ThenInclude(serials => serials.Country)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    return new Result<SingleStudioInfo>
    {
        Code = 200,
        Type = ResponseType.Success.ToString(),
        Response = new SingleStudioInfo
        {
            Id = studio.Id,
            Name = studio.Name,
            Logotype = studio.Logotype,
            Serials = new Container<SerialShortInfo>
            {
                ItemsCount = studio.Serials.Count,
                Items = studio.Serials.Select(serial => new SerialShortInfo
                {
                    Id = serial.Id,
                    Country = new CountryShortInfo
                    {
                        Id = serial.Country.Id,
                        Name = serial.Country.Name
                    },
                    CurrentSeriesCount = serial.CurrentSeriesCount,
                    SeriesCount = serial.SeriesCount,
                    DateOfIssue = serial.DateOfIssue,
                    Description = serial.Description,
                    IsMovie = serial.IsMovie,
                    Title = serial.Title,
                    Year = serial.Year,
                    OriginalTitle = serial.OriginalTitle,
                    PreviewImageUri = serial.PreviewImageUri
                }).ToList()
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Одни из сгенерированных ответов:

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "type": "Success",
  "response": {
    "itemsCount": 3,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Кошечка из Сакурасо",
        "originalTitle": "さくら荘のペットな彼女",
        "description": "В старшей школе искусств университета Суймэй есть множество общежитий, а есть доходный дом «Сакура». ...",
        "year": 2012,
        "country": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "日本語"
        },
        "dateOfIssue": "2012-10-01T00:00:00",
        "previewImageUri": "/sakuhin/nenpyo/2012/12_sakurasou/sakurasou.jpg",
        "isMovie": false,
        "seriesCount": 24,
        "currentSeriesCount": 24
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Гранбелм",
        "originalTitle": "Granbelm",
        "description": "События аниме \"Гранбелм\" начинают свой ход, когда во время полнолуния старшеклассница Мангэцу Кохината встречает Сингэцу Эрнесту Фуками, иммигрантку и новую ученицу из Германии! ...",
        "year": 2019,
        "country": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "日本語"
        },
        "dateOfIssue": "2019-07-06T00:00:00",
        "previewImageUri": "/online/poster/1ba3a02a45.jpg",
        "isMovie": false,
        "seriesCount": 12,
        "currentSeriesCount": 3
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Взрыв!",
        "originalTitle": "Btooom!",
        "description": "Сетевая игра \"Взрыв\" (БТУМ) насчитывает несколько миллионов игроков по всему миру, среди них Сакамото Рёта, лучший игрок Японии входящий в десятку лучших мира. ...",
        "year": 2012,
        "country": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "日本語"
        },
        "dateOfIssue": "2012-10-04T00:00:00",
        "previewImageUri": "/6582/3ef9deb00b7f68976d4d4e8f881106cfac8ee0da_hq.jpg",
        "isMovie": false,
        "seriesCount": 12,
        "currentSeriesCount": 12
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Класс StudioShortInfo это entity EF (проецируется в таблицу БД) или это dto-класс для передачи между слоями?

Comment: Все представленные классы это DTO. Ни одна модель не отдается в чистом виде

Comment: Подумайте, не хотите ли вы сделать ctor для StudioShortInfo и писать `_context.Studios.Select(studio => new StudioShortInfo(studio));` как первый шаг к автомапперу ну и вообще короче же и нагляднее. Кроме того, если это dto то вычисления идут на стороне клиента (как .AsEnumerable), зачем вам IQueryable<StudioShortInfo>?

Comment: зачем код и тип добавлять в json? это же и так в ответе придет. класс Result<T> Тоже судя по всему не нужен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Узнаю знакомые тропки. (:

Класс Result добавляет к некотором "результату" два поля: (Status)Code и (Result)Type.

Вы сделали это через дженерики, можно было сделать базовый ResultBase c этими полями и отнаследоваться. Весь код, который мне приходилось писать - ему было достаточно либо знать, что у класса есть status потому что это был слой транспорта, либо коду было всё равно на транспорт, потому что там был саксесс и важно было знать тип (и тип и так понятен).

Я в своё время проходил это увлечение дженериками, позже стал стараться использовать только там где реально необходимо.

Позже, читая умные книги, где рекомендуют "предпочитайте композицию наследованию" я вообще стал обращать внимание, что нужно проектировать классы вообще без этих вот Code и Type.

Посмотрите на примеры [проектов Real world](https://github.com/gothinkster/realworld) - даже несмотря на то, что они передают информацию между крайне разными платформами и языками программирования (а потому информация о типе теряется) -- они предпочли не создавать поля тип и статус. Вообще.

Поэтому рекомендую задуматься над простыми вопросами "а зачем они вообще мне понадобились эти два поля? Что я ими делаю, зачем? Можно ли как-то обойтись без них". Код без этих постоянных переливаний из класса в класс станет гораздо лаконичнее и понятнее.